# How to use "as" to set alias for joined tables in oracle 10

Tags: oracle10g

I wrote this, and it is wrong syntax, help me fix it, I want 'T' to be an alias of the result of the two inner joins.

```
select T.id 
from table1 
  inner join table2 on table1.x = table2.y  
  inner join table3 on table3.z = table1.w as T;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't directly name the result of a join.  One option is to use a subquery:

```
select T.id
from (
  select *
  from table1
  inner join table2 on table1.x = table2.y
  inner join table3 on table3.z = table1.w
) T
```

Another option is subquery factoring:

```
with T as (
  select *
  from table1
  inner join table2 on table1.x = table2.y
  inner join table3 on table3.z = table1.w
)
select T.id
from T
```

Answer (score 10):

You cannot use aliases to name the "entire" join, you can, however, put aliases on individual tables of the join:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1
   inner join table2 t2 on t1.x = t2.y
   inner join table3 t3 on t3.z = t1.w
```

In the projection, you will have to use the alias of the table, which defines the `id` column you are going to `select`.